# Create a sub-group for each group

Tags: python

I have a data frame  as follows:

```
orderid     ordername 
1           a
1           b
1           c
2           d
2           e
3           f
```

I want to create a suborder_id column for each orderid.

```
suborder_id
   1
   2
   3
   1
   2
   1
```

I used:

```
def get_suborder_id(???)
     df['suborder_id'] = ????
     return df
df = df.groupby('orderid').apply(get_suborder_id)
```

However, I am not particularly clear on how it actually works. Please help me understand on this!!!

Comment: It's not clear what you want this column to be

Comment: @sacul.. edited the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like `cumcount`

```
df['subid']=df.groupby('orderid').cumcount()+1
```